# Enabling auth mode sso("Login Via google") after install argocd 2.4.3

Tags: argocd

Recently we migrated from 2.3.3 to 2.4.3 and we are using google sso with argocd by script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.4.3/manifests/install.yaml .

It used to show "Login Via google" In 2.3.3 with out any additional settings but now its showing only uid/pwd boxes.

we are already injecting argocd-cm
dex.config: |
connectors:
- config:
issuer: [https://accounts.google.com](https://accounts.google.com/)
clientID: {{ .Values.dex.sso.clientId }}
clientSecret: $dex.sso.clientSecret
type: oidc
id: google
name: Google

I googled and got to know that setting auth-mode to sso might enable "login-via-google" login button

```
argo server --auth-mode sso --auth-mode ...
```

We tried to change the auth-mode to sso but I could not find a way to set the auth-mode in https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/v2.4.3/manifests/install.yaml or via env variable in argocd-cm

Please help me in this regards

Regards,
Shubhendu

Comment: Adding the `dex.config` block should do it. Check the `argocd-server` Deployment's logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure OAuth 2.0 Client ID setup for argocd in here https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?authuser=1&project=my-foo-project (change to what project you want to use)

I recommend to use Helm to deploy ArgoCD or in most common cases with terraform, seems you have million lines default deployment in your links.

Values to have in helm values file (hopefully you can locate reference to those in default deployment files you provided):

```
configs:
  cm:
    url: https://${ domain }
    dex.config: |
      connectors:
        - name: Google
          id: google
          type: google
          config:
            issuer: https://accounts.google.com
            clientID: ${ oidc_credentials.clientID }
            clientSecret: ${ oidc_credentials.clientSecret }
            redirectURI: https://${ domain }/api/dex/callback
            adminEmail: ${ oidc_credentials.adminEmail }
            serviceAccountFilePath: /tmp/oidc/googleAuth.json
            groups: # Control which groups are authorized to access argocd
            %{~ for _, groupEmail in authorized_groups ~}
              - ${ groupEmail }
            %{~ endfor ~}
dex:
  # -- Additional volumeMounts to the dex main container
  volumeMounts:
  - mountPath: /tmp/oidc/
    name: google-service-account-key
    readOnly: true
```

Your expected view when visiting argo URL should look as this below:
[image]